# Nested promises not resolving until a button is clicked

Tags: angularjs, promise

I'm building an AngularJS app (using 1.2.0 RC1) that uses a REST API for saving data that the user has entered. The user will enter data about a company and it consists of two core components that I need to save:

- The company details
- Contacts within that company

I have 1 REST method to call to save the company and then I have another that I call for each contact to be saved.

I planned to use `$q` to track all the requests and resolve them once it's completed.

The problem I've hit is that although the REST API is being called successfully and all my data is being saved my controller isn't being notified when all the promises have resolved *until* I click a button on the screen, such as the `add contact` button. I've tried eliminating the REST API as a source of problems but it still happens when simulating delayed jobs using `setTimeout`.

Here's my `service` module:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['restService'])
    .factory('service', ['client', '$q', function (client, $q) {
        return {
            create: function (name, people) {
                var deferred = $q.defer();

                setTimeout(function () {
                    console.log('saved company ' + name);

                    var promises = people.map(function (person) {
                        var dfd = $q.defer();

                        setTimeout(function () {
                            console.dir(person);
                            console.log('Person saved');
                            dfd.resolve();
                        }, 100);

                        return dfd.promise;
                    });

                    $q.all(promises).then(deferred.resolve);
                }, 100);

                return deferred.promise;
            }
        };
    }]);
```

And here's my controller:

```
angular.module('club', ['myApp'])
    .controller('RegisterCtrl', ['$scope', 'service', function ($scope, service) {
        $scope.addPerson = function () {
            $scope.company.people.push({
                firstName: '',
                lastName: '',
                email: ''
            });
        };

        $scope.removePerson = function (person, index) {
            $scope.company.people.splice(index, 1);
        };

        $scope.save = function (company) {
            service.createClub(company.name, company.people).then(function () {
                console.log('And we\'re done');
            });
        };

        $scope.company = {
            name: '',
            people: []
        };
    }]);
```

So when I invoke the `save` method (which is `ng-click` bound to a button) I will have a console.log set like this:

```
saved company
Object
Person saved
Object
Person saved
```

Notice there's no `And we're done` output. As soon as I click the button that `addPerson` is `ng-click` bound to I get the final message output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular doesn't magically watch all timeouts. It needs a hook to be told that something might have changed, which triggers a `$digest` loop.

You can do it manually, by calling `$scope.$apply()`, or by using inbuilt handlers (like `ng-click`). But for this use case there's also the `$timeout` service which you can use in place of `setTimeout`.

See [API Reference/ng/$timeout](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24timeout).

Comment: Where would you call `$scope.$apply`? I'm binding the `controller.save` using `ng-click` to a `button` on the UI so that's how to trigger the whole process.

Comment: As mentioned by Glen, `$timeout` is your best choice here. Inject `$timeout` in your service and replace `setTimeout(...)` with `$timeout(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

It is highly recommended to use the AngularJS `$http` service to communicate with your REST API since it takes care of updating the model for you.

It returns a promise that you can chain `success` and `error` handlers to, so it's very versatile.

Translated to your code, you could have a service like this:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .factory('person', ['$http', function ($http) {
        return {
            create: function (data) {

                // Return promise
                return $http.post('/yourApiUrl', data);
            }
        };
    }]);
```

and a controller like this:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('yourController', ['person', function (person) {

        $scope.company = {
            name: '',
            people: []
        };

        $scope.addPerson = function(data){

            //Save person to API
            person.create(data)

                // Success handler
                .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

                    // Parse person from response (e.g. if your API 
                    // returns the created object after a POST)
                    var person = data;

                    // Add person to company
                    $scope.company.people.push(person)
                })

                // Error handler
                .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

                    // Handle error
                });

        };

    }]);
```

By returning the promise from your service, you can customize the `success` and `error` handlers in your controller, allowing very flexible solutions.

And you don't have to create your own promises. AngularJS will handle it all for you.

I hope that helps!

Comment: I'm using Azure mobile services as the REST API which provides a JS client API that I'd prefer to not rewrite so I can't use `$http`.

Comment: When working with 3rd party scripts, you can call `$scope.apply()` whenever you want AngularJS to update the bindings.

Comment: But where do you call `$scope.$apply()`? I've tried doing it inside the `$scope.save` method of my controller but that errors out because it's already in an `$apply` (since `save` was triggered by a `ng-click` binding). I've also put it around the `$q.all` but that didn't solve it either

Comment: It depends on what your code is doing. If your third party code performs a change that you need to be reflected inside your AngularJS world, you need to perform a `$scope.$apply()`. By looking at your sample code, the callback specified in the save handler (where your log "And we're done") should have a `$scope.$apply()`. If you create a plnkr with your code, I'll be more than happy to have a look...

Answer (score 0):

You always want to call deferred.resolve() and deferred.reject() from within a scope context. In your case, you are calling code from outside the angular framework (setTimeout, and in real use your JS client API for Azure mobile services as you mentioned in a comment), so you should wrap dfd.resolve() in a $rootScope.$apply() (and don't forget to inject $rootScope into your service).

http://plnkr.co/edit/3sCHEjrtMdqCvFQ7ILTD

This Plunkr shows a working example. If you change the $rootScope.$apply(dfd.resolve()) back to just dfd.resolve(), it has the problem you described in your question.

Note that is is probably also better to use $rootScope.$apply(function(){dfd.resolve()}) instead, for the reasons listed in this article:

http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html