# AngularJS SharePoint - callback hell stopped working

Tags: angularjs, sharepoint, q

my formerly working sharepoint service stopped working - i don't know why, it just stopped.

in my controller i call the service function, that should return some data that i can put into my scope variable:

```
var getItemsFromSPService = function () {
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function () {
        SPService.loadItems($scope.gridParams).then(function (result) {
            //result.items is always undefined!?
            $scope.gridParams.data = result.items;
            $scope.gridParams.itemsCount = result.itemsCount;
        });
    });
};
```

here is my service - that worked until yesterday :/

```
angular.module('app').service('SPService', ['$q', function ($q) {

var service = this;

service.currentUser = {
    id: null,
    login: null,
    fullLogin: null,
    roles: []
}

service.gridParams = {};

service.loadItems = function (gridParams) {

    service.gridParams = gridParams;
    //don't load SP user twice...
    if (service.currentUser.id != null) {            
        return loadListData();
    }
    else {            
        return loadCurrentUser().then(function () {
            return loadListData();
        })
    }        
};


//get current SP user and save to service.currentUser
var loadCurrentUser = function () {

    var deferred = $q.defer();

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = clientContext.get_web();
    clientContext.load(web);

    var currentSPUser = web.get_currentUser();
    clientContext.load(currentSPUser);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
    function () {
        service.currentUser.id = currentSPUser.get_id();
        service.currentUser.fullLogin = currentSPUser.get_loginName();
        service.currentUser.login = service.currentUser.fullLogin;
        if (service.currentUser.login.indexOf("\\") > -1)
            service.currentUser.login = service.currentUser.login.slice(service.currentUser.login.indexOf("\\") + 1, service.currentUser.login.length)

        deferred.resolve(service.currentUser);

    }, function () {
        alert('Fehler beim Laden des Users aus dem SharePoint')
    })

    return deferred.promise;
}

var loadListData = function () {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    var result = {
        items: [],
        itemsCount: null
    }

    //RowCount 
    getQueryRowCount().then(function (rowCount) {

        result.itemsCount = rowCount;

        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var web = clientContext.get_web();
        clientContext.load(web);
        var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(service.gridParams.listName);
        clientContext.load(list);

        var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
        var queryString = (buildQueryString(false));
        query.set_viewXml(queryString);

        var listItems = list.getItems(query);
        clientContext.load(listItems);          

        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        function () {
            //success
            var resultItems = [];
            var listItemEnumerator = listItems.getEnumerator();
            while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {

                var listItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
                var listItemId = listItem.get_id().toString();

                //get specific item including EffectiveBasePermissions, after that, copy and push to result array
                getListItem(listItemId).then(function (returnedItem) {
                    var newItem = {};
                    angular.forEach(service.gridParams.columns, function (col) {

                        if (col == "Author")
                            newItem[col] = returnedItem.get_item(col).get_lookupValue();
                        else
                            newItem[col] = returnedItem.get_item(col);                            
                    })
                    newItem['WriteAccess'] = returnedItem.get_effectiveBasePermissions().has(SP.PermissionKind.editListItems);
                    result.items.push(newItem);

                    //result.items is there!!!! it holds the SP data
                });
            }

            deferred.resolve(result.items); //result.items is emtpty in debugger!?

        }, function () {
            //fail
            alert('Fehler beim Laden der SharePoint Liste.');
        });
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}

var getQueryRowCount = function() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = clientContext.get_web();
    clientContext.load(web);
    var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(service.gridParams.listName);
    clientContext.load(list);

    var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
    var queryString = (buildQueryString(service.gridParams, true));
    query.set_viewXml(queryString);
    var listItems = list.getItems(query);
    clientContext.load(listItems);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        function () {
            //success
            deferred.resolve(listItems.get_count());
        },
        function (sender, args) {
            //fail
            alert('Fehler beim Laden der Element-Anzahl.');
        });
    return deferred.promise;
}

var getListItem = function (listItem_id) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(service.gridParams.listName);
    var listItem = list.getItemById(listItem_id);
    clientContext.load(listItem);
    clientContext.load(listItem, 'EffectiveBasePermissions');
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        function () {
            //success
            deferred.resolve(listItem);
        },
        function (sender, args) {
            //fail
            alert('Fehler beim Laden der Element-Berechtigungen.');
        });
    return deferred.promise;
}

//other crud functions. saving works e.g. - same $q logic


}]);
```

do you see anything that is not correct?

btw. i would like it much more if the SP.SOD.execureFunc() would be inside the service and that the service would return the items. so i could do something like this in the controller:

```
SPService.loadItems($scope.gridParams)
```

thank you very much!

Comment: Wall of code. What have you tried to debug your service? And what is it with the "btw" sentence?

Comment: okay sorry. please have a look at the part at the end of loadListData, just before the promise is returned. the you can see in the comments what i debugged. "before" deferred.resolve(result.items) the result.items array is filled with data. but that data seems not to be returned. debugger shows "undefined".

Comment: the "btw" sentence:  to use sharepoint client object model you have to load sp.js.  SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', callback) first. but that function does not return data from the callback function. at least i have not found a way. that's what i would like to do .

Comment: while debugging i discovered some strange behaviour. in the very beginning of "loadListData" you can see "getQueryRowCount().then(...". that function returns the correct rowCount. but directly after that it jumps to "deferred.resolve(result.items); //result.items is emtpty in debugger!?" which should only happen after the result.items got filled. after that it continues with the function, fills the data in the array BUT does not resolve it (thats what happened - and should not happen - before.) so result gets undefined. any idea?

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution, but it's rather dirty and i don't understand why the old code stopped working.

i transferred the $scope as parameter to my main service function. then changed

```
var loadListData = function () {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    ...
                result.items.push(newItem);
            });
        }

        deferred.resolve(result.items); //result.items is emtpty in debugger!?

    }, function () {
        //fail
        alert('Fehler beim Laden der SharePoint Liste.');
    });
});
```

to

```
var loadListData = function () {
    service.scope.gridParams.data = [];

    ...
                service.scope.gridParams.data.push(newItem);
                service.scope.gridParams.itemsCount = result.itemsCount;
            });
        }

    }, function () {
        //fail
        alert('Fehler beim Laden der SharePoint Liste.');
    });
});
```

that looks **SO** wrong.. manipulating the $scope within a service function. i even left out the main $q deferring stuff in the function

i just want to **return** the values back to the function caller. i just don't know why it stopped working.

i'm really interested in a clean, best practice solution! :)

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

second possible way is to change "deferred.resolve(..)" to "scope.$apply(deferred.resolve(...))". you have to pass $scope or $rootScope as parameter to the service function, too. but that seems not as bad as manipulating $scope variables directly in the service function.

i don't know if it's better to use $rootScope, according to this thread it is:
[Nested promises not resolving until a button is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18374357/nested-promises-not-resolving-until-a-button-is-clicked)

thanks!